# Ожидание нажатия клавиши Space

Tags: python, python-keyboard

появился вопрос с библиотекой keyboard. Я хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии клавиши Space срабатывала функция каждый раз, или же если я нажму Backspace то вызывает другую функцию, с Backspace вроде получилось, а со Space нет.

```
from keyboard import add_hotkey, wait
class Main:
    def ProcessRaid(self):
        add_hotkey('Backspace', lambda: main.ShowMainMenu())
        add_hotkey('Space', lambda: main.ProcessRaid())
        wait('Space')
        if main.RandomFear(80):
            RandomVariantNothingFound = randint(0, 3)
            if RandomVariantNothingFound == 0:
                print("Хмм.. Похоже здесь ничего нет!")
            elif RandomVariantNothingFound == 1:
                print("Что я тут вообще забыл?")
            else:
                print("Зря я сюда влез!")

main = Main()

main.ProcessRaid()
```

Comment: Я такое через простой цикл делал: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/16534e3e15a85ffae50696b0707522908638a221/pyautogui__keyboard__examples/hotkey__start_pause_quit.py, в отдельном потоке: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/autoclick_in_game__pyautoit.py#L26

Comment: Ничего не понятно)

Comment: Исправил! Вопрос закрыт!

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите, самостоятельно ответ с решением :)